# How do I be sure that I don't respawn in a strange place?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I died and spawned in a random place. I entered this site and I used some advice, and I used a compass and found my way back. But what if I die again, will I spawn away from home? Or was that just a glitch?

I'm scared of trying to die, because I don't want to do through that experience again. If I sleep a few more times in my bed, will that help me spawn home once I die? If I have more beds in my house, and I sleep in every one of them, does that affect my spawn point? Thanks for reading, any advice will help!

Answer (score 1):

Beds in mine craft will set your spawn point sleeping in multiple beds will only move your spawn point to the most recent bed you slept in so placing multiple beds won't change much but I recommend you protect your bed because if it gets destroyed your spawn point will be your original point on the map

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one bed set as your spawnpoint. Where was your bed located in your house? If you don't give yourself enough space to spawn, when you die, the message "Your home bed is missing or obstructed" will appear. Make sure you but your bed in a spacious area, and also, make sure that your bed is actually there. Keep your house protected from mobs at night. Sleeping in multiple beds will not increase your chances of a spawnpoint being set, it'll just move your spawnpoint around from bed to bed. Also, a good tip to keep in mind when playing Minecraft is to build your house relatively close to your original  spawn.